# Styles and JS applicable just inside a <div>

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Is it possible to have .css and .js files applicable just inside a div? I build a React projects and I'm inserting it in my website. My React runs inside `<div id="reactApp"></div>`. The React generates css and js files.

In my website, I include the files and the  that the files are supposed to run.

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Content Here -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Content Here -->

  <div id="reactApp"></div>

  <!-- Content Here -->
<body>
</html>
```

It works fine, but all the .css that I generated in my React application is affecting the styles outside the `<div id="reactApp>`. How can I make styles applicable only inside the div?

I thought about an iFrame, but I have links inside of the `<div id="reactApp"></div>` which navigates to other parts of the website. Using an iFrame, it navigates to other parts of the website, but inside the iFrame, not the whole website.

Comment: add a parent seletor to your styles

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: `#reactApp .yourClass` ?